# How to work with calculated columns in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't know if the title of this question is understood, but what I mean is this.

I have a table of sales and I need to "format" the table adding on query some columns to indicate the total, change rate (which i took form another table) and the total amount rated on other currency.

So my query looks like:

```
SELECT SalesID,SalesType,SalesDate,CurrencyType,
       case when CurrencyType = 1 then Total else 0 AS TotalOnLocalCurrency,
       case when CurrencyType = 2 then Total else 0 AS TotalOnOtherCurrency,
      (TotalOnLocalCurrency/dbo.GetCurrencyRate(SalesDate)) + TotalOnOtherCurrency) Total
FROM Sales
```

If this scenario possible, I mean I tried to do this but I got this error:

> Invalid column name 'TotalOnLocalCurrency'.

Comment: *temporal* = time-related, e.g. being able to reconstruct the facts for any given time in the past. Often achieved by having `ValidFrom/ValidTo` columns in your data, so that you can always reconstruct what e.g. an address looked like five years ago...

Comment: didn't you misspell about this TotalOnLocalCurrency/dbo.GetCurrencyRate(SalesDate)? maybe TotalOnLocalCurrency.dbo.GetCurrencyRate(SalesDate) ?

Comment: .dbo.GetCurrencyRate(SalesDate) is a function to get the currency rate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either put the whole formula in the subsequent lines, or use `CROSS APPPLY` for this:

```
SELECT SalesID,
       SalesType,
       SalesDate,
       CurrencyType,
       TotalOnLocalCurrency,
       TotalOnOtherCurrency,
      (TotalOnLocalCurrency/dbo.GetCurrencyRate(SalesDate)) + TotalOnOtherCurrency Total
FROM Sales
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN CurrencyType = 1 then Total else 0) CxA(TotalOnLocalCurrency)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT case when CurrencyType = 2 then Total else 0) CxB(TotalOnOtherCurrency)
```

Comment: sorry for this question but what CxA and CxB means?

Comment: They are just aliases for the cross applied subqueries.   You can put whatever you want, but I use them to mean `CrossApplyA` and `CrossApplyB`

Comment: @JCooper I got it from MartinSmith I think

Comment: @JNK I think we all have a few good tricks we learned from Martin Smith

Answer (score 1):

Your are getting the error because you have aliased the expression `CurrencyType = 1 then Total else 0 AS TotalOnLocalCurrency`. You cannot refer to alias column names in the same select clause, this violates logical query processing rules. Instead, either refer to the expressions themselves or wrap the expressions in a table expression and query against the table expression.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use column aliases that you introduce within the same query. If you're on SQL Server 2005 and newer, I would use a CTE (Common Table Expression) to handle this.

```
;WITH SalesData AS
(
    SELECT 
        SalesID, SalesType, SalesDate, CurrencyType,
        TotalOnLocalCurrency = CASE WHEN CurrencyType = 1 THEN Total ELSE 0 END,
        TotalOnOtherCurrency = CASE WHEN CurrencyType = 2 THEN Total ELSE END 
    FROM Sales
)
SELECT 
   SalesID, SalesType, SalesDate, CurrencyType,
   TotalOnLocalCurrency, TotalOnOtherCurrency,
   Total = (TotalOnLocalCurrency/dbo.GetCurrencyRate(SalesDate)) + TotalOnOtherCurrency) 
FROM  
   SalesData
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like:

```
select 
SalesID,SalesType,SalesDate,CurrencyType,
TotalOnLocalCurrency,TotalOnOtherCurrency,
TotalOnLocalCurrency/dbo.GetCurrencyRate(SalesDate)) + TotalOnOtherCurrency as total from
(
    SELECT SalesID,SalesType,SalesDate,CurrencyType,
           case when CurrencyType = 1 then Total else 0 END AS TotalOnLocalCurrency,
           case when CurrencyType = 2 then Total else 0 END AS TotalOnOtherCurrency
    FROM Sales) t
```